# The data types nvarchar(max) encrypted with with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC' xxx) are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, encryption, sqldatatypes, deterministic

```
var countryCode = new SqlParameter("@countryCode", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dto.Country);
countryCode.Value = byteArray;
var country = new SqlParameter("@country", "country");
country.Value = "country";

var rawUsers = DbContext.Users.FromSqlRaw("Select u.* from AspNetUsers u join AspNetUserClaims uc on
                                            u.Id = uc.UserId where uc.ClaimType = @country and
                                            uc.ClaimValue = @countryCode", country, countryCode)
                              .ToList();
```

ERROR:

> [17:16:22 ERR] Error:The data types nvarchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_WITH_AKV', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyDatabase') and varbinary(2) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_WITH_AKV', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyDatabase') are incompatible in the equal to operator.

By the way, db columns are encrypted most nvarchar columns are encrypted.

I've been looking for solutions to make it right. But seems nothing works. Did I miss anything? Anyone who can help?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. You can't compare an encrypted `nvarchar(MAX)` to an encrypted `varbinary(2)` with the equals (`=`) operator.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I do understand that. But just understanding it won't solve it. get my point? I've been looking for ways to make it compatible. Tried conversions as well but no one works. That is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 4):

`AspNetUserClaims.ClaimValue` is `nvarchar(max)`

`@countryCode` is `varbinary(2)`

[AlwaysEncrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) is client-side encryption.  So the encrypted value of the parameter must match *exactly* the encrypted value of the column.  Consequently there can be no server-side implicit conversions to do the comparison and the data types must match exactly.

So you need to declare the parameter as `nvarchar(max)` as well.  EG

```
   var countryCode = new SqlParameter("@countryCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar,-1);
   countryCode.Value = dto.Country;
```

Comment: Hi @David Browne , thank you. However, I've already tried it. I won't get an error on the solution but I the collection I'm expecting is empty. I tried using profiler and this is the error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your connection string has "Column Encryption Setting=Enabled;" setting. I had this issue when my parameters from C# code matched exactly including size and precision for decimal types to SQL parameters but without this setting in your connection string, you get the above error.